# How can VBA determine which software product it's currently running within..?

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-word, vba

Many software products have VBA incorporated into them. This includes Microsoft Office of course, but there are many 3rd-party products which have chosen to include VBA as well. A quick Google search turned up names like AutoCad, WordPerfect, PowerTerm, and ScriptWorx.

If one wishes to use #If/#EndIf directives to design a Sub or Function to work in multiple environments, how can VBA detect which one it's currently running in..??

This is a bit different than detecting if a product is installed, in which case CreateObject() and an ErrorHandler could be used. Also, checking the References collection would not be definitive, since a VBA project might have multiple references to products other than the current one. For instance, an Access project might have a reference to Excel, and vice-versa (as many of mine do).

Say, I want to write a function that returns the name of the current file. Here's some pseudo-code using Access and Excel as examples.

```
Public Function CurrentFilename() As String
    #If EnvironmentName="Access" Then
        CurrentFilename = Access.Application.CurrentProject.Fullname
    #ElseIf EnvironmentName="Excel" Then
        CurrentFilename = Excel.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Fullname
    #Else
        MsgBox "Current VBA software environment is not recognized."
    #End If
End Function
```

Is this possible..? If so, what's the magic constant or function to replace 'EnvironmentName'..?

Comment: I found this 2 articles that if maybe don't solve your question, can be interesting for you: https://www.wizdoh.com/how-to-communicate-with-other-applications-using-vba/ - https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/appactivate-activate-folder-or-application-if-already-open/

Comment: Have you looked into the `Application.Name` property? I can't confirm it works outside of office products, but it seems to be consistent with MS stuff..

Comment: @Chris Meurer, post that as an answer.

Comment: Chris Meurer, that nailed it. Solution right under my nose. As Gordon says, post that as an answer..! I'll vote for it as my solution.

Comment: @David G. I'm a bit familiar with inter-product communication; I've got about a dozen references in my main project file. One of them is for a nicer version of the Access-to-Excel exporter which outputs a query to a spreadsheet, and because it's VBA allows the full environment of Excel formatting, instead of the lame built-in widget that Access provides. =-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your best bet will be the `Application.Name` property. I can't confirm it works for all VBA implementations, but it appears to be consistent with MS products.
From the MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221371(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Right under my nose, lol..!! Yes, that works with Access, Excel, and Word.